# How can I pass a data from UIViewController to a UITableViewController that is embedded in a container placed on that UIViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uicontainerview

I have an ios app written in swift and there I have a `UIViewController` with a container on half of the screen. This container has embedded `UITableViewController` and I want to display there some data that I'm fetching from my webservice. The problem is that to fetch the data from web service I need an unique id number that I store in the `UIViewController`. So how can I pass that data from one controller to another?

Comment: All the usual methods will work. For instance you could use a global variable / shared instance or post the ID number into an instance variable on the view controller.

Comment: Hm how could I post the ID number into an instance variable on the view controller? could you show me some example for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a [**project on github**](https://github.com/DuncanMC/test) (written in Objective-C) that does exactly what you want. It has the horribly unoriginal name "test".

It has a master view controller with 2 child view controllers, each of which is a subclass of `UITableViewController` set up to manage static table views. (That detail doesn't really matter. It's the method of setting up connections between parent and child view controllers that addresses your question.)

The idea is that you set up your child view controller in a container view and link it in with an embed segue.

When you use an embed segue then `prepareForSegue` fires when the views are loaded. In your `prepareForSegue` you save a reference to your child view controller(s) if you need to call it/them, and make yourself each child's delegate if you need *it* to call *you*.

The code would be different in Swift but the concept is identical.